# Python doesnt print XOR Operation

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import binascii
import sys


def main():
    password = [0x3b, 0x65, 0x21, 0xa, 0x38, 0x0, 0x36, 0x1d,
                0xa, 0x3d, 0x61, 0x27, 0x11, 0x66, 0x27, 0xa,
                0x21, 0x1d, 0x61, 0x3b, 0xa, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x27,
                0xa, 0x66, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x30, 0x37, 0x36]

    passbytes = [0x3b, 0x65, 0x21, 0xa, 0x38, 0x0, 0x36, 0x1d,
                 0xa, 0x3d, 0x61, 0x27, 0x11, 0x66, 0x27, 0xa,
                 0x21, 0x1d, 0x61, 0x3b, 0xa, 0x2d, 0x65, 0x27,
                 0xa, 0x66, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x30, 0x37, 0x36]

    for i in password:
        print(password[i] ^ 0x55)
```

Im a Python Newbie trying to Solve a XOR CTF Flag but for some reason python doesnt want to print anything out...

Would be very grateful for help!

Comment: It should be `i ^ 0x55`.

Comment: The reason why it isn't doing anything is because you aren't calling `main()` after you define the function.

Comment: `for .. in` iterates over elements, not indexes.

Comment: @Barmar and bhlsing U were both right, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the for loop:

```
for one_password in password:
    print(one_password ^ 0x55)
```

`for .. in` iterates over elements, not indexes

Comment: Thank you very much, and I also had to call main()